# Some basic methods are unrecognised by Adapterview

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-adapterview

I have a listactivity where I read/set diferent controls such as textviews, buttons or listviews in OnCreate method and also I use diferents methods of this controls inside onCreate method. Now that I know that everything works well I would like to introduce a viewpager so I can fling between diferent layers.

I have read that I have to include my code into public Object instantiateItem of my pageadapter but there are some methods that are not recognised:

1. setListAdapter
2. getListView
3. getResources
4. getString
5. When I use the list, I said that onCreate method, the context for the list was this. Now which context do I have to put?

How can they be recognised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. setListAdapter
2. getListView

   ```
   ListView listVi = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
   listVi.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```
3. getResources

   ```
   view.getResources()
   ```
4. getString

   ```
   view.getResources().getString()
   ```
5. When I use the
   list, I said that onCreate method, the context for the list was
   this. Now which context do I have to put?

   ```
   view.getContext();
   ```

PS. view is the View variable where I inflate the layer.